# Flask application on AWS EB always gives me a 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, flask, aws-ebs

I can run my application on localhost without an issue, but as soon as I upload it to AWS EB, I get the `500 Internal Server Error`.

Here is my `app/__init__.py` file:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
```

And my `application.py` file:

```py
from app import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port='8080', use_reloader=True, debug=True)
```

Is there a misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that AWS EB expects:

```py
application = Flask(__name__)
```

***Solution***:

```py
application = app = Flask(__name__)
```